# SQL Server - Setting Formulas and/or Calculated Fields as Variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there some method I can use with SQL Server to create variables I can use in my queries that are based on formulas/calculated fields? The examples that I've seen so far have all only dealt with setting variables = to literal values.

For the queries I'm working on, some of the calculated fields I need to get to are based on extensive formulas between multiple other calculated fields, often using type conversions along the way. When I want to then build further, using these all of these different calculated fields for nested IIF statements, it's starting to get extremely cumbersome to write them out inside that statement in their entirety.

It would be so much easier and look so much cleaner if I could just refer to these calculated fields as simple variables rather than copy pasting them in spanning 5+ lines and looking like a complete mess

Answer (score 3):

You can create a table-valued function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tfu_RPT_SEL_Benutzer] 
(
     @in_mandant varchar(3)
    ,@in_sprache varchar(2) 
    ,@in_show_alle bit = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(   
    SELECT 
         BE_ID AS RPT_ID 
        ,@in_mandant AS RPT_MDT_ID 
        ,BE_Vorname AS RPT_Vorname 
        ,BE_Name AS RPT_Nachname 
        ,BE_User AS RPT_User 
        ,
        CASE 
            WHEN LEN(ISNULL(BE_Vorname + ' ', '') + ISNULL(BE_Name, '') ) > 0 
                THEN ISNULL(BE_Vorname + ' ', '') + ISNULL(BE_Name, '') 
                ELSE BE_User 
         END AS RPT_Name 

        ,0 AS RPT_Sort 
    FROM T_Benutzer 


    UNION 


    SELECT 
         0 AS RPT_ID 
        ,@in_mandant AS RPT_MDT_ID 
        ,'' AS RPT_Vorname 
        ,'' AS RPT_Nachname 
        ,
        (
            SELECT TOP(1) 
                CASE UPPER(@in_sprache) 
                    WHEN 'FR' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Kurz_FR 
                    WHEN 'IT' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Kurz_IT 
                    WHEN 'EN' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Kurz_EN 
                    ELSE T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Kurz_DE 
                END AS RTR_Kurz 
            FROM T_RPT_Translations 
            WHERE (RTR_Status = 1) 
            AND (RTR_MDT_ID = 0) 
            AND (RTR_ReportName = 'All') 
            --AND (RTR_IsFlag = 1) 
            AND (RTR_ItemCaption = 'NA') 
            --AND (RTR_Code = 1) 
        ) AS RPT_User 

        ,
        ( 
            SELECT TOP(1) 
                CASE UPPER(@in_sprache) 
                    WHEN 'FR' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Lang_FR 
                    WHEN 'IT' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Lang_IT 
                    WHEN 'EN' THEN T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Lang_EN 
                    ELSE T_RPT_Translations.RTR_Lang_DE 
                END AS RTR_Lang 
            FROM T_RPT_Translations 
            WHERE (RTR_Status = 1) 
            AND (RTR_MDT_ID = 0) 
            AND (RTR_ReportName = 'All') 
            --AND (RTR_IsFlag = 1) 
            AND (RTR_ItemCaption = 'NA') 
            --AND (RTR_Code = 1) 
        ) AS RPT_Name

        ,999999999  AS RPT_Sort 
    WHERE @in_show_alle = 1 
)
```

Then you can use CTEs inside the table valued function.

```
DECLARE @i integer 
SET @i=5

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        BE_ID
        ,BE_ID * @i as idmul 
    FROM T_Benutzer
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE idmul > 62000
```

And query from the function

```
DECLARE @in_mandant varchar(3)
,@in_sprache varchar(2) 
,@in_show_alle bit = 1

SET @in_mandant = '0'
SET @in_sprache = 'DE'
SET @in_show_alle = 'true' 

SELECT * 
FROM tfu_RPT_SEL_Benutzer( @in_mandant, @in_sprache, @in_show_alle )
WHERE RPT_User = 'N/A'
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple-but-ugly solution is to have nested select statements:

```
Select a+(b*c) from (
    select 
       x*y AS a, 
       price/amount AS b, 
       acos(y) AS c
    from TheTable
) as q
```